# See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use developer mode to see the message

Tags: php, magento, magento2, mode

I tried to install the MAGENTO 2 on a local machine. I get the
following error:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use developer mode to see the message.

Comment: Check log file of Magento

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put Magento in developer mode as stated in the error.
Go into your source directory using a command line tool (console on linux or CMD on windows) :

```
cd your/local/magento
```

Then set Magento in dev mode :

```
php  bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

You can check this page for more information on command line tools provided by Magento : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html

Also as stated by Vikal you should check the logs which are located in

```
your/local/magento/var/log/
```

Typically you would check system.log and exception.log as a start. Also if nothing is written in magento logs don't forget to check apache and php error logs.

Cheers.